# Getting Outlook Redemption to work on 64-bit operating systems?

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, outlook-redemption

Our servers are upgrading to Windows 10 64-bit (which is also using Office 64-bit products) and I noticed that in this environment, the old Outlook Redemption code I run in my MS Access VBA applications no longer work due to Access being unable to load the usual dll files (Redemption.dll, StrStorage.dll, dynapdf.dll). Is there a way to get this to work in 64-bit Office?

Comment: Maybe its not a problem with 64-bit OS, but 64-bit Office? Edit: If it is this (http://dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) then it officially supports Office 64-bit. So maybe you just have to update it?

Comment: Yeah, it may be 64-bit Office, sorry I should have clarified. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Have you seen my edit above regarding updating Redemption?

Answer (score 0):

You will need  x64 bit version of the app + dll's  used. So if you using say tree-view, there not a x64 bit version. Same goes for  any  "add in", and that includes Redemption. You course of action is to find a x64 bit alternative, or hope that a x64 bit version of Redemption is released. Same goes for activeX calendar control, or any  other add-in, or activeX control(s) you use. You have to ensure that x64 bit versions of such controls or add-ins are available before you can really adopt office x64 bit version.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the bitness of Access (where your code is running) matches the bitness of Outlook / MAPI system.

Since Redemption (unlike OOM) is an in-proc COM library, it bitness must match the bitness of your code (COM system takes care of that). But since Redemption loads the MAPI system in-proc, the bitness of the MAPI system must match the bitness of the host.

See http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#ErrorCreatingRedemptionObject for more details.

Comment: Yes the bitness of Outlook matches the bitness of Access (both 64-bit) but the .dlls don't load. Do I need to re-download anything? Last time I installed anything with Redemption was years ago

Comment: What exactly happens? Do you get an error? What is it?

Comment: I made another post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58050830/outlook-namespace-logon-keeps-asking-me-for-a-profile-keeps-asking-for-password to describe some initial errors, but the short answer is "everything is throwing errors" every step of the way through